# What is this 4-propeller plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

My dad noticed it flying quite low today, sadly we do not have a better photo.

4-propellers and uniquely shaped tail assembly.

Plane was spotted in northern Poland, around 9.30AM, near border with Russia/Kaliningrad.

[image: Plane photo]

Comment: Have a look at my answer - and especially the many images of each type of craft. I do not know the exact location but (see map in my answer) given the appearance and the various locations mentioned, the IL38 appears the more likely choice. I may be wrong, of course :-).

Comment: See the map in my answer - can you identify the location at which the photo was taken and the direction that the photographer was facing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Where* you spotted it would help with probabilities.

However - the tail marks it out as a Maritime Patrol aircraft, of which the only low-wing 4-engine one is the P-3 Orion operated primarily by the US and Oz.

Comment: Added time & location details to question, thank you.

Comment: There's one other low-wing 4 engine maratime patrol aircraft, the [Ilyushin Il-38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-38). Although indeed this looks more like the P-3 Orion.

Comment: I think your answer would benefit from some information as to what exactly about the tail makes it obviously a maritime patrol aircraft.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek Agreed.  The [MAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_anomaly_detector) boom on the tail is there specifically for submarine hunting.

Comment: For interest: I'd have suggested a P3 - New Zealand (where I live) also operates them although I believe they are about to be phased out.

Comment: @Sanchises See my answer.

Comment: How did you know that it was a maritime patrol aircraft based on the tail?

Comment: @dalearn: The [MAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_anomaly_detector) sticking out of the tail.

Answer (score 22):

The fuselage extension at the back of the empennage is similar to that of a Lockheed P-3 Orion
[image: Lockheed P-3 Orion from Wikipedia]

Answer (score 10):

While I personally would have thought it was an Orion P3 (as it resembles the Orions flown by the NZ airforce), I suggest that Sanchises suggestion of an Ilyushin IL38 (not II38) seems more likely. This is based on numerous online images of both craft 'at a distance' and the location. The wing shape appears (to me) more like that of the IL38, and one could 'pretend' (given the small image size) that the outer engines appeared somewhat smaller, as is the case with IL38's 'at a distance'.

The IL38 is or was operated by USSR/Russia and India.
Depending on how close the location was to the Russian border the aircraft may have been in Russian or Russian-Kaliningrad airspace. The latter would seem to be an entirely likely location for such an aircraft. 
It is also entirely possible (and I have no knowledge either way) that Russia has overflight rights for military aircraft between Russia proper and the Kaliningrad exclave.

[image]

Apart from the US Navy (whose aircraft may turn up almost anywhere :-) ) none of the [18 operators of the P-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_P-3_Orion#Operators) are anywhere near the location noted. .

Many P3 Orion photos [**here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=orion+p3&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuxu73-8LhAhWk3mEKHcTkApAQ_AUIDigB&biw=1344&bih=726)
Many Ilyushin IL38 photos [**here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ilyushin+Il-38SD&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOpP-H-8LhAhXrv1QKHTW8BGAQ_AUIDigB&biw=1344&bih=686)

Here is an image of a US Navy P3 Orion.
**It will be seen in many of the images linked above that from a distance the wings tend to appear slightly swept *forward* due to the larger rear root to tip taper compared to the leading edge taper.**

[image]

**________________________________**

**Here is a diagram of an IL-38**

**Looking at the many IL38 images linked above shows the wing to appear at a distance as thinner and squarer ended than a P3 Orion.**

[image]

Comment: I don't see the radar bulge though, which I think should show up even on the low quality picture.

Comment: @Sanchises In photos, not all have them, and some have what look like garden sheds on top :-). I looked for other feature differences as well, but could not convince myself with any degree of certainty that the RADAR dome was missing as opposed to masked. Knowing the photographers location and line of bearing may help.

Comment: Among the P-3 opeartors, the Netherlands, Norway, Portugal and Spain  are all in NATO, so could reasonably be flying near Kaliningrad. Amsterdam and Oslo are closer to Kaliningrad than Moscow is.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the Netherlands haven't operated the P-3 for over a decade. The aircraft were given to Germany (for free).

Comment: @jwenting Thanks. I just followed the link in the answer, which said "operators", implying current. I've edited the answer to point to Wikipedia instead. Russell, could you please edit your claim about none of the operators except the USN being close? Germany is right next door. Germany, Greece, Norway, Portugal and Spain are all in NATO so could be flying over Poland. Berlin and Oslo are closer to Kaliningrad than Moscow is, and Athens is only about 50km farther away.

Comment: Also, the aircraft was described as flying low so, unless it appeared very close to the border, it was probably on the Polish side. It's not like it was at 30,000ft and was 20 miles from the observer. And even if Russia does have overflight rights to reach Kaliningrad, they'd be over Lithuania and Belarus, not Poland. That seems unlikely anyway, since Lithuania is in NATO and Kaliningrad is accessible via the international waters of the Baltic.

Comment: My dad reviewed all the answers, he says the plane certainly looked more like P3 Orion rather than IL-38 all things considered. It was about ~10km from Vistula Bay shores. Sadly, we have no clue who could possibly be the operator of the plane.